# How to let an outside service access my local enviournment

Tags: node.js, localhost, backend

My backend is running in a local enviournment at http://localhost:1337 - using node js and strapi headless CMS.

I'm integrating credit card transaction and their system needs to send a POST request to my backend but it cannot be done since my enviournment is local.

Is there a simple way (hopefully) to enable access from the outside to my local env?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like, running an app on a publicly addressable server?

Comment: Yes I mean that my server is not yet public because I'm at development stage

Comment: Yeah, you need a public IP. You probably have one through your ISP, try `ifconfig` on Mac, `ipconfig` on Windows

Comment: Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you’re exposing your localhost like that just for development purposes.

Check out https://ngrok.com/ and https://serveo.net/

Both are solid options and can be configured to expose PORT 1337

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, the serveo.net solution is simply amazing!